# What is the right way to pull my changes from gitlab to remote server?

Tags: git, gitlab

Let's say I have some private project in GitLab.

To access this project from my local machine I'm:

1. Generate ssh keypair.
2. Add public key to my Account (mygitlab.com/-/profile/keys).
3. Do `git clone git@mygitlab.com:mygroup/myproject.git`on local machine.
4. Work.

Then I want to deploy my project on remote production server `1.2.3.4`. Ideally I want to just `ssh` into this server, clone my project and then do `git pull` every time I want to update production deployment. But I can't access my repository from production server because there is no ssh keys in `1.2.3.4:/home/www-data/.ssh/`, so if I'm trying to do `git clone` or `git pull` I get `Permission denied` error.

What I supposed to do in this situation?

From my opinion I should have ability to generate ssh keypair on production server and add public key to my project. But there is no way to associate public key with project - only with account. And I don't want to associate public key for production server with my account because it's methodologically wrong - there is many developers in our team and production server is not associated with me in any special way.

Comment: `I should have ability to generate ssh keypair on production server and add public key to my project. But there is no way to associate public key with project` But there literally is. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/

Comment: Git labs has a [dev-ops platform](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/devops-platform/).

Read more on the topic [here](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/devops/).

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks, deploy keys is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using a CI/CD system to handle deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I supposed to do in this situation?

Like you say, you should `generate ssh keypair on production server and add public key to my project` by going to repository, then on the left settings->repository and then in the middle there are "deploy keys". Paste the public key into deploy keys and choose a unique name. After that, you can use that key to clone. There is also documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/ .